# Worms Reloaded - Using Teleport makes my rig say g'bye!

Tags: worms-reloaded, technical-issues

I've got an ATI 4870, Q6600 @ 3Ghz, 4GB RAM, Asus P5B Deluxe running on Win7 32Bit.

Every time a worm uses Teleport my FPS go from 60 down to 1 for about half a minute. What gives?

Same thing happens during level loading, it takes aaaaages to load.

Comment: Since this is rather a bug with the game, I suggest you report this on the [Team17 forums](http://forum.team17.com/forumdisplay.php?s=caa093ba43e0dcde715e73d2313fe5a9&f=107) or the [Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=941).

Comment: Similar thing happened to me with Worms World Party - the longer I stay at the main menu the more my FPS drops.  Despite having an uber gaming rig, after about 5 minutes it takes several seconds to see my cursor movement register.

Comment: If you're running a Q6600 @ 3Ghz, you're doing some serious overclocking... the Q6600 is an Intel Core 2 Quad 2.4Ghz processor.

Comment: @Powerlord: I know, so? My Q6600 can handle up to 3.2 GHZ with air cooling, but my Motherboard/RAM combination doesn't allow me to go for 3.2 GHZ without too high a CPU temp. i.e. I need higher VCore and other stuff to get my rig prime95 stable running 8+h.

Comment: As for the problem, it's still there, and I stopped playing. Because the AI keeps using Teleport and I just can't bear waiting half a minute after each teleport to resume normal playing.

Comment: @NoCanDo: In my experience, overclocking can introduce strange performance issues.

Comment: Can we please stop talking about overclocking already? It's not that because I tested it on stock performance as well.

Comment: @Powerlord, Q6600 processors can easily be clocked to 3.4GHZ on air alone, I have 3.0GHZ on mine and it has run fine for over 3 years. 3.0GHZ on that processor is completely fine, as long as your temps are sane.

Answer (score 2):

It is an issue with the game, I actually have a similarily spec'd machine as you and certain things make the game run poorly, such as teleporting, or the gas that comes out of the skunk.

I also stopped playing it due to the frustrating lag, particularly during multiplayer.